# Задача на платформе Stepic, цикл while

Tags: python

Условие такое: Напишите программу, которая считывает со стандартного ввода целые числа, по одному числу в строке, и после первого введенного нуля выводит сумму полученных на вход чисел.

```
s = 0
n = int(input())
while n != 0:
    s = n + a
    if n == 0:
        print(s)
```

Comment: Вопроса то у вас и нет собственно. Хотя понятно о чём он должен быть, но формально вопрос надо таки написать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 0
while True:
    n = int(input())
    s = s + n
    if n == 0:
        print(s)
        break
```

Comment: Если есть явное и однозначное условие прекращения цикла, то решать задачу через `whilt True + break` - так себе решение...

Comment: @strawdog можно, конечно, ```while n! = 0```, но тогда переменную ```n``` придётся определять и до цикла, прописывая ей, например, пустое значение, и в самом цикле

Comment: @strawdog Да ну нет, "вечный цикл" + выход через `break` по условию - вполне хороший паттерн, в противном случае придётся какие-то флаги и проверки лишние в код вводить. В каком-то смысле это аналог `return` из функции, но без функции.

Comment: Тут если и докапываться, то к тому, что лучше написать `s += n` и что проверка должна быть до сложения (в данном случае это не важно, но вдруг признак выхода был бы не `0`, а `-1` или вообще надпись `quit`, хотя тогда ещё `int` нужно было бы перенести), но так то это мелочи.

Comment: @CrazyElf С проверкой до сложения согласен, мой косяк)

Comment: @GameLinux Ну в данном случае прибавка нуля ничего не изменит, так что это нельзя назвать косяком, просто небольшая нерациональность )